# How to use a lib instaled with NPM in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, npm

I'm using Laravel 5.8 at the moment, and I can't figure out how to use NPM inatalled scripts on my views.

For example, [this simple and nice icon picker (fontawesome-iconpicker)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fontawesome-iconpicker), in the console:

```
$ npm i fontawesome-iconpicker
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ fontawesome-iconpicker@3.2.0
added 1 package and removed 1 package in 16.388s
```

Installed, after that my package.json have '"fontawesome-iconpicker": "^3.2.0",' in the dependencies, so i run

```
npm run dev
```

And it compiles fine. 
Now, when I trie to use the lib in my view the console shows

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).iconpicker is not a function
```

My question is about npm install in Laravel, not only this picker, already researched a lot, but never found out what I'm doing wrong or what is missing here.

===== UPDATE =====

So, lib is working now, but I'm not completly sure in one of the steps.

After run 'npm i fontawesome-iconpicker', there is one step before 'npm run dev', in Laravel at least. Open your 'resources\js\app.js', and under 'require('./bootstrap');' you can define the require like:

```
window.iconpicker = require('fontawesome-iconpicker');
```

After this you can run 'npm run dev' and the lib will be compiled in the 'public/js/app.js' file and be reachable by the name you defined('iconpicker').

BUT, when i tried this with other lib, the 'npm run dev' failed, because didint found the 'require('NAME_OF_OTHER_LIB_ALREADY_INSTALLED_WITH_NPM');'

So, the question remains ^^"

Comment: Delete the node_modules directory and try a fresh install. I would recommend yarn if you cant use npm. command: sudo yarn install, after that try run command: npm run watch.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same kind of problem and I am pretty sure it comes from Laravel mix, in fact jquery is loaded in your app.js file, but that file is loaded like this :

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

So if you use jquery in your vue, it's not yet loaded and you get that kind of errors.

If you remove the "defer" it will work but the best way is to wait for jquery get loaded before using it.
You can write your javascript directly in your ressource/js/app.js to avoid that kind of problem, it will be compilled when you run `npm run watch` and the compilled file will be in public/js/app.js

Comment: I did had problems with 'defer' also. But is not related with this NPM problem. Actually I did make the ib work, but not 100% sure this works, going tu update the question.

Comment: What library do you try to include? The name you have to use in the require() is the same as the one in your package.json, can you give the error message?